# Android: call Service's super.onDestroy() outside onDestroy()

Tags: android, handler, ondestroy

I have a Service which is playing music. I've implemented [fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284044/1181261) **like this**:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    volume=1.0f;
    fade_handler.post(fade_out);
    super.onDestroy();  
}
```

This is **fade_out Runnable**:

```
private Runnable fade_out = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        player.setVolume(volume, volume);
        if(volume>0.0f){
            volume-=0.05f;
            fade_handler.postDelayed(fade_out, 200);
        }
        else{
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            stopForeground(true);
            //here should be super.onDestroy()!!!!!!!
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that now **super.onDestroy()** get's called before **fade_out** finishes - so I want to call super.onDestroy() inside this runnable - **but how**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the best idea to do things like this in `onDestroy()` because this method is supposed to do cleanup. I suggest you doing the following:

- Create a method like `void fadeOutAndStop()`.
- Set it to post a Runnable which fades out the volume and the calls `stopSelf()` (or the method you use to stop the service now).
- Use the `fadeOutAndStop()` method when you need to stop your service.

This way you won't even need to do anything special in `onDestroy()`, and the design will be much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed seems to be a better solution. One thing though - how do I call this function from my activity? Using [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html)? All I did before was stopService(intent).

Comment: I think I found the answer. I need to bind the service.

Comment: @PrimožKralj No, no, AIDL is an overkill. All you need is a [Binder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binder) unless you're doing some interprocess communication or multithreading.

Comment: Ah, spasiba ;)
One more short question: if I use bindService(...) in my Activity, is it ok if I stop the service with stopSelf() or should I also somehow unbind it in Activity afterwards?

Comment: @PrimožKralj Нет проблем! `stopSelf()` is absolutely okay to use regardless of whether you bind to your service or not. In fact, if you use `startService(Intent)`, it is even required to stop the service explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be YourServiceClassName.super.onDestroy(), but as Malcolm points out it's not a good idea.