# Android - running a method periodically using postDelayed() call

Tags: android, postdelayed

I have a situation in an Android app where I want to start a network activity (sending out some data) which should run every second. I achieve this as follows:

In the `onCreate()` I have the code:

```
tv = new TextView(this);
tv.postDelayed(sendData, 1000);
```

The `sendData()` function:

```
   Handler handler = new Handler();
   private Runnable sendData=new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            //prepare and send the data here..
            handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
            handler.postDelayed(sendData, 1000);    
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
};
```

The problem come in like this: When user presses the back buttons and app comes out (UI disappears) the `sendData()` function still gets executed which is what I want.  Now when user re-starts the app, my `onCreate()` gets called again and I get `sendData()` invoked twice a second. It goes on like that.  Every time user comes out and starts again, one more `sendData()` per second happens.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it my `new Handler()` creating problem?  What is the best way to handle this?  I want one `sendData()` call per second until user quits the app (form application manager).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why don't you create service and put logic in `onCreate()`. In this case even if you press back button service will keep on executing. and once you enter into application it will not call
`onCreate()` again. Rather it will call `onStart()`

Comment: Thank you. I created a service activity and it works well.  I wanted the service task to continue running even when the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 104):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
        Toast.makeText(c, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
      }
    }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 31):

Perhaps involve the activity's life-cycle methods to achieve this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      handler.post(sendData);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
}


private final Runnable sendData = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            //prepare and send the data here..


            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);    
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
};
```

In this approach, if you press *back-key* on your activity or call `finish();`, it will also stop the *postDelayed* callings.

Comment: Thank you for the point.  In fact I wanted the postDelayed task to continue even when the user press back.  Tried this code and it works as expected: postDelayed call stops when the user presses the back button.

Answer (score 16):

You can simplify the code like this.

In Java:

```
new Handler().postDelayed (() -> {
    //your code here
}, 1000);
```

In Kotlin:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
   //your code here
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below  its working on my side in below code your handler will run after every 1 Second when you are on same activity

```
 HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
                handlerThread.start();
                handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
                runnable = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                        }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler h = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (msg.what==0){
            // do stuff
            h.removeMessages(0);  // clear the handler for those messages with what = 0
            h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000); 
        }
    }
};


 h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could experiment with different activity flags, as it sounds like multiple instances.

"singleTop" 
"singleTask" 
"singleInstance"

Are the ones I would try, they can be defined inside the manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set **andrid:allowRetainTaskState="true"** to Launch Activity in Manifest.xml. If this Activty is not Launch Activity. you should set **android:launchMode="singleTask"** at this activity