# Hide and make visible button every 5 second interval

Tags: android, button, show-hide

Can it possible to make a button on screen which automatically visible and gone every 5sec interval?
By using this

```
b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

we can visible and

```
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

we can hide it.But I can't manage to make it by usin the time interval.
Any idea?please share.

Comment: Use a `Handler.postDelayed()` call, such as is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845172/android-running-a-method-periodically-using-postdelayed-call).

Comment: Better create Service and run your stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
new CountDownTimer(9000000, 5000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     if(b.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
      b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     else
      b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
   //Restart timer if you want.
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: make sure you cancel the timer when you goto onPause

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways, one is a Handler and Runnable:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable alternate = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Alternate visible and not
            mHandler.postDelayed(alternate, 5000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mHandler.postDelayed(alternate, 5000);
    }
}
```