# How to print accelerometer values every X seconds in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, delay, accelerometer

i want to print accelerometer values every 3 seconds. this is my code so far

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {              
            x = a * x + (1 - a) * event.values[0];
            y = a * y + (1 - a) * event.values[1];
            z = a * z + (1 - a) * event.values[2];
              new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {                     
                      printValue();
                  }
              }, 3000);                        
        }

    }
```

it's delaying output only when application launch ,what is my mistake and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you want to print them regardless if they change?

Comment: yes, and every 3 seconds

Comment: You need to move your handler from your onSensorChanged

Comment: write an infinite for loop and set a delay of 3 second there, hence each time execute for loop, it will delay 3 sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove your Handler from `onSensorChanged()` so it will run constantly. Right now it will only execute if you have a change in your sensor reading. Also, you need to add a call to rerun the Runnable again, otherwise it will only execute once.

```
//Outside of onSensorChanged(), perhaps in onCreate() of your Activity
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        printValue();
        new Handler().postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: thanks, it works for my case , for this case i'm using your solution, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with `postDelayed`, but I would hazard a guess that each of the calls to `run` are being delayed by 3 seconds, however each delay is being counted in parallel, where as you are looking to have them delayed sequentially so to speak.

Depending on how often `onSensorChanged` is called you might be better off doing something like checking the elapsed time since the last call, and if > 3 seconds then running `printValue`

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(/*time elapsed > 3 seconds*/)
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {              
            x = a * x + (1 - a) * event.values[0];
            y = a * y + (1 - a) * event.values[1];
            z = a * z + (1 - a) * event.values[2];
              new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {                     
                      printValue();
                  }
             }, 3000);                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this will print after 3 seconds all values, and having the temporal check outside the sensor type check is incorrect, as the values won't update. during this time

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a thread for this, you can have this start up in the onCreate so its always running and so your not waiting for it to start when onSensorChanged happens.

```
Thread printvalue = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      printValue();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printstacktrace();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This only executes `printValue()` once.

Answer (score 0):

What your current code is doing is waiting for a change in the sensor, then waiting 3sec and printing.

If you want to print every 3seconds you need to re-post your runnable when it's done. postDelayed is just delaying before execution, you need to start another 'timer' of 3seconds when you have done your print.

check here : [Android - running a method periodically using postDelayed() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845172/android-running-a-method-periodically-using-postdelayed-call)

there is a call to postDelayed(runnable) inside the run method of the runnable itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the value if was updated after 3 seconds. So, it could happen after 3 seconds and some milliseconds, but you don't have to manage a different thread.

```
private final static long ACC_CHECK_INTERVAL = 3000;
private long lastAccCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    lastAccCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){              
        x = a * x + (1 - a) * event.values[0];
        y = a * y + (1 - a) * event.values[1];
        z = a * z + (1 - a) * event.values[2];

        if(currTime - lastAccCheck > ACC_CHECK_INTERVAL) {
            printValue();
        }
    }

}
```