# Best approach to update local db from remote db periodically

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I am using the Volley library to pull data from a remote db.

I have locked the fetching process inside a ProgressDialog because, if not, I noticed the data could or could not reach the app. By locking it, I make sure the data is there to be shown to the users.

Now, I have implemented a local db so the user doesn't need to fetch from the remote db the same information every time.

The information fetched, only comes when a certain condition is met. This is the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_meals
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN date_of_meal AND DATE_ADD(date_of_meal, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND email = '$email'
ORDER BY date_of_meal DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The process goes like: Android app sends petition to PHP file -> PHP file runs SQL -> PHP file answers -> Android app listens to the answer.

So my question is:

How can I make the fetching process run in the background, and make it run every given amount of time?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

**Apparently it is a bad practice to do periodic requests to a server. So instead, I am going to handle them on demand. Thank you all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition making periodic fetching is a [very bad practice](http://cafbit.com/entry/battery_cost_of_periodic_mobile)

So you should really do it only on demand - and if you already activate the radio for sending so at least piggy back everything else.
Anyway the correct approach would be to create a service ( or intent service) where you post you data and it syncs it to the network ( I use it between realm and remote backend succesfully)

Comment: But my question remains: assuming I put everything on the service, I would still need to make the service work every n amount of time. How?

Comment: as Doug Stevenson wrote - alarm manager would probably be the best option - if it is a location based so geofence works well also

Comment: Okay. I will research on this, and try to come up with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: again - try to avoid making periodic request - and if you already do them so bring all the rest of the data and precache - like on DB. the data transfer take only several seconds but it takes for the device to shut down the TRANSMITER around 40-70 seconds

Comment: I'm thinking on just adding a refresh button, or a pull-to-refresh action. Is that what would it be called "good practice"?

Comment: if you have no choice you have no choice - right ?like if you need to send something for immediate response - but if you can wait ? wait. if you can "guess" what the user will want - cache it on previous or next request. it is better to take a bit more data (with smaller images for example) than to open request frquently - and if you open - sync all the rest, analytics, data not synced and more

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Handler to run it repeatedly:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (!isStopped){

        //Do your work here

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
  }
}, 0);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845172/android-running-a-method-periodically-using-postdelayed-call).

Comment: But, as far as I know, Volley was created so people could stop using HttpRequest + AsyncTask. Isn´t this like a contradiction?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice that you were using Volley. I guess you can replace the ASynkTask with Volley. My point was that you can take advantage of a Handler to repeat requests

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to do this, but one solution might be to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a repeating intent to be delivered to a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) you create in your app.  The Service can then do whatever you need.  It will take some research to best assemble these components.

Comment: I will do some research in to this. Thanks.