# How to create a fade out button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a button onclick to fade out the music and call the media player to stop?

I want this to be over 5 sec

I have tried to make a timer like code, but i dont get how to make it work - can you guys help me?

```
float volume = 1;
float speed = 0.05f;

    public void FadeOut(float deltaTime); 
{ 
mpMain.setVolume(1, 1); 
volume -= speed* deltaTime; } 
public void FadeIn(float deltaTime1); 
{ 
mpMain.setVolume(0, 0); 
volume += speed* deltaTime1; } 


}}
```

Comment: Show the code that you've tried and why it didn't work please

Comment: ive tried a bunch of codes, and delete it when it didnt work and startet over... the latest is ....   public void FadeOut(float deltaTime);
  {
   mpMain.setVolume(1, 1);
      volume -= speed* deltaTime;

  }
  public void FadeIn(float deltaTime1);
  {
      mpMain.setVolume(0, 0);
      volume += speed* deltaTime1;

  }
  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   FadeOut.
   
   }}

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)

setVolume with a timer should probably be pretty good I think

Comment: `public void FadeOut(float deltaTime);` what's this? Why is there a semi-colon after the method declaration? Can you post the code formatted in the question please

Comment: @ZimZux, please edit your question to contain your code instead of posting the code in the comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884590/android-how-to-create-fade-in-fade-out-sound-effects-for-any-music-file-that-my ... was the latest page i used to try figuring this out

Comment: Again, post that in the question. It's relevant. With the code that you did to try to implement the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

[Android: How to create fade-in/fade-out sound effects for any music file that my app plays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884590/android-how-to-create-fade-in-fade-out-sound-effects-for-any-music-file-that-my)

and the code that you posted, is that you set the volume directly to 1, and ignore the volume variable that you're changing. Instead use the `volume` variable exactly as they do in the solution to the other question. This also needs to be called several times via a timer.

deltatime should be the amount of time that passed since the last time the method was called. This is to keep the fade consistent if the phone lags or something.