# Fade Volume on Button Click

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm writing an app to Play music on APP INVENTOR 2 by MIT. I have a Button to Control volume. Which when i Click must return to set value in Player's Volume. I can adjust the volume. but i can't get it to reduce gradually with time.

In example: An audio track is playing in volume 100% 
                  Then the Volume down button is pressed
                   Volume of the audio track must be set to 25% but Gradually.. like within 5 seconds. (not suddenly)

Creating a smooth Volume Fade. Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you need something like volume fadeIn/fadeOut check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884590/android-how-to-create-fade-in-fade-out-sound-effects-for-any-music-file-that-my/29246026#29246026).

Comment: Hey, I can't implement code to App inventor?

Comment: Probably you'll need to work on 'timer'. I don't think there is an exact solution for you but you can do it by using timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a While loop to control the volume fade In and fade Out:

[image: Screenshot]